# Get list of entity of one to many relationship hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a column mapped as

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentStage")
private List<Stage> childStages = new ArrayList<Stage>();
```

when I use hibernate to query this column:

```
projectionList.add(Projections.property("childStages"),"childStage");
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Stage.class,"e")
                .setProjection(projectionList)
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    List<Stage> result = cr.list();
```

It returns

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

I understand and researched a lot that we cannot get a list in hibernate ??

Is there a solution for this problem or another solution to achieve the above?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: what is your class name where column is `List<Stage> childStages.`
Also can you add here projectionList Projection code

Comment: Class name is "Stage" `ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();`

Comment: harshit I am bit confuse here, can you please describe what your want to achieve here?  do you need just childStages  which belong to any stage?